# swift lazy var use let constant

Tags: ios, swift

I have many buttons with same `size`, i want to set the constant width from lazy var, how should i do that? `JRTopView.buttonWidth` and `buttonWidth` both don't work.

```
  class JRTopView: UIView {
        let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 150
        lazy var leftButton: UIButton! = {
            let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(-30, 30, JRTopView.buttonWidth, buttonWidth)
            return btn
        }()
        lazy var rightButton: UIButton! = {
            let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(-30, 30, JRTopView.buttonWidth, buttonWidth)
            return btn
        }()
    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
It's interesting, if i use `self.buttonWidth` it works in `leftButton`, but not `rightButton`.
[image]

Comment: `JRTopView.buttonWidth` doesn't work because the buttonWidth is a instance property and not a calculated class property. Try to use `self.buttonWidth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `buttonWidth` is an instance property, the only way to access it is through an instance of `JRTopView`.

You can either create a new instance and do `yourInstance.buttonWidth` if you are outside this class, or just do `buttonWidth/self.buttonWidth` if you are inside.

However, being a constant that will always have the same value for all instances of `JRTopView`, it would make more sense to promote it to a class level:

`static let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 150`

This should allow you to do `JRTopView.buttonWidth`.

Comment: if i use self.buttonWidth it works in leftButton, but not int rightButton

Comment: Both `leftButton` and `rightButton` code blocks only run once, the difference between the two is the `lazy` keyword in `leftButton`. With `lazy`, you are allowed to reference `self` inside as this block is only ran once you reference to it in code (aka, after `init`, once the instance is ready). However, with `rightButton`, since it does not have the `lazy` keyword, it will be ran as soon as a new instance of `JRTopView` is created (think of it as eager initialisation), which happens before `init` is run, so `self` is not ready and cannot be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

This builds in Xcode 7.1

```
class JRTopView: UIView {
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 150
    lazy var leftButton: UIButton! = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(-30, 30, self.buttonWidth, self.buttonWidth)
        return btn
    }()
    lazy var rightButton: UIButton! = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(-30, 30, self.buttonWidth, self.buttonWidth)
        return btn
    }()
}
```